# How to code pinescript in order for the signals to display throughout history?

Tags: pine-script

Currently the default All Candlestick Pattern indicator can only display around 50 labels. Is there some code that I can put in so that it will display every signal all the way back to day 1?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `max_labels_count` in study parameter to increase the number of labels to 500. This is the limit.